# PHP - How can I get the name from input type hidden and $_POST to another php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

I wish can pass the value of `getvenueurl` to another php named map.php .

I use input type hidden to to echo in current page:

`<input type="hidden" name="getvenueurl" value="<?php echo $show_venue['url']; ?>"/>`

and I wish when i click the button `<a href="map.php" target="_blank"><input type="button"  class="button" value="MAP" style="width:100px;">` in map.php show the correct value of `getvenueurl`.

In current page:

```
 <?php
$read_venue = mysql_query("select * from venue where theme_name = '$title'");

while($show_venue = mysql_fetch_array($read_venue)) 
{

?>
<form method="post" action="#tab5">
<center><table border="1" class="venuetb">

    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="getvenue" value="<?php echo $show_venue['venue']; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="getvenueprice" value="<?php echo $show_venue['price']; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="getvenueurl" value="<?php echo $show_venue['url']; ?>"/>

        <td style="width:20%;"><center><div class="imgvenue"><img src="<?php echo 'venueimg/'.$show_venue['venueimg']; ?>" /></div></center></td>

        <td ><center><div class="bine"><?php echo $show_venue['venue']; ?> - RM <?php echo $show_venue['price']; ?></div></center></br>
        <div class="dv"><p>&nbsp;<b>Address : </b><?php echo $show_venue['address']; ?></p>
        <p>&nbsp;<b>Detail : </b><?php echo $show_venue['detail']; ?></p>
        <b>&nbsp;Contact No: </b><?php echo $show_venue['contact']; ?></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20%;">
        <center><a href="map.php" target="_blank"><input type="button"  class="button" value="MAP" style="width:100px;"></a>
        <input type="submit" class="button" style="width:100px;" value="CHOOSE" name="choose_venue"></center>


        </td>

    </tr>
        </table></center><br>
</form>
<?php
        $_SESSION['theurl'] = $show_venue['url']; 

}   
?>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['choose_venue']))
{
    $getvenue = $_POST['getvenue'];
    $getvenueprice = $_POST['getvenueprice'];



    $savevenue = mysql_query("insert into selectvenue(user,title,venuename,venueprice) values('$username','$title','$getvenue','$getvenueprice')");
    if($savevenue)
        {
            echo"<center>$getvenue  save.</center>";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed.";

        }
}
?>
</div>
```

I have try to use session to pass the value of `getvenueurl` but seen it is failed, because it will only show the last column value for all output that in while loop.

In map.php:

```
    <table class="mapping">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php
        $theurl = $_SESSION['theurl'];
         echo $theurl;?>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the correct value to my map.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can pass value through anchor tag this way..i hope this will help u.

```
<a  href="map.php?getvenueurl=<?php echo $show_venue['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><input type="button"  class="button" value="MAP" style="width:100px;"></a>
```

Comment: hi thanks for you reply but still the same as previous

Comment: u can get value from url by $_GET['getvenueurl']

Comment: u mean declare `$_GET['getvenueurl']` in map.php ?

Comment: oh yeah !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! just this simple way ~ thanks thumb up

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 <a href="map.php" target="_blank"><input type="button"  class="button" value="MAP" style="width:100px;"></a>
```

write this code

```
<input type="button"  class="button" onclick="submit_to_map()" value="MAP" style="width:100px;">
```

Then place this javascript code on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_to_map() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form-id");
    form.action = "map.php";
    form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Then you can get the value of all elements with $_POST[] inside the form from map.php. Hope this will help you

Comment: With this you can get not just getvenueurl but also all input (including hidden) field values.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm you have `<?php session_start(); ?>` on beginning of each page !